# Why does this angularJS directive's changes not reflect on the view?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm putting together an angular directive that provides a nested treeview with checkboxes.

When the user checks a checkbox, I would like the directive to automatically check all child checkboxes too. And vica versa when unchecking. It looks like the model gets updated (I did some $logging), but the view does not reflect the change for any checkboxes except the one the user clicked on.

If I add $scope.$apply to my listeners, I get an error stating that an $apply is already in progress.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

The data hierarchy looks as follows (coffeeScript):

```
[
        {
            name: "Top1"
            nodes: [
                {
                    name: "Sub1"
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            name: "SubSub1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            name: "Top2"
        }
    ]
```

Directive as follows (coffeeScript):

```
myApp.directive 'ccCheckboxTreeview', () ->
    {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^ngModel'
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        }
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/directives/checkboxTreeViewTemplate.html'
        controller: ($scope, $log) -> 
            $scope.nodeCheckClicked = (node) ->
                if node.checked
                    uncheckChildren(node)
                else
                    checkChildren(node)

            loopAndSet = (node, trueOrFalse) ->
                $log.info node.name, trueOrFalse if node?

                if node.nodes? && node.nodes.length > 0
                    for n in node.nodes 
                        loopAndSet n, trueOrFalse

                node.checked = trueOrFalse if node?
                return

            uncheckChildren = (node) ->
                loopAndSet node, false
                return

            checkChildren = (node) ->
                loopAndSet node, true
                return
    }
```

Template as follows:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.checked" ng-click="nodeCheckClicked(data)" />{{data.name}}</label>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul data="{{ngModel}}">
    <li ng-repeat="data in ngModel" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:**
It works perfectly now, and I have no idea why. Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/M7ICpYgolEIa0FTJQSvU

Comment: Plunker or JSFiddle, please.

Comment: Hi Craig, I'll upload one tonight, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have to close this question. The code in my question now works fine, without any changes. scope.$apply not required either. I have no idea why it did not work previously.

Answer (score 0):

Directives are outside of the scope of the digest cycle. In other words, you should just need to call scope.$apply() after you make a change to have it updated in the DOM.